# including one form in the other in a windows application

Tags: .net, winforms

I have created a windows application using file->new->project->windows application.
in there i created 2 forms.now i want to invoke the two forms ina third form created in another windows application.pls help

Comment: You couldn't *possibly* come up with anymore useful tags?

Comment: Vb.net or c# or something else?

Comment: the forms tag is for HTML. (OP hover your mouse over it to see that)

Comment: added the tags  `windows visual-studio application` but he still didn't tell us the language.

Comment: @CodyGray the OP didn't say anything about .net or winforms.

Comment: @eznme He described it fairly accurately. The question says *forms*, and "windows applications". That's the verbage of WinForms. Granted, you do have to read between the lines a little bit. We weren't given much to work with.

Answer (score 0):

To use classes from another projects (forms are classes):

1. Classes must be `public`.
2. You must add target project by right-clicking on your current solution and then `Add`, `Existing project...` and selecting your project
3. Use classes by specifying their full name with namespace or use `using` directive.

The second task is to use one form as a container for others. This article can help: [How to: Create MDI Child Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)